# Проблема с преобразованием Double в String(Java)

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

возникла проблема. При загрузке таблицы из XLSX файла, я получаю вместо String значения, значения Double(так как библиотека не видит заданный тип элементов столбца). После я преобразую это число в String при помощи String.valueOf(), но получаю число по типу: 3.151162E6. Можно ли как-то это число удобно преобразовать в "3151162"?
P.S. Я бы мог написать алгоритм, просто интересно можно ли сделать это иначе.

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет форматированный вывод. [Здесь](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) подробнее.

```
String sf2=String.format("%2.2f",3.151162E6);
System.out.println(sf2);
```

Вывод

```
3151162.00
```

Answer (score 0):

*я получаю вместо String значения, значения Double(так как библиотека не видит заданный тип элементов столбца)*

А что за библиотека ? У ApachePoi есть другие варианты получения данных.

1. getNumericCellValue
2. getDateCellValue
3. getStringCellValue

Можно посмотреть тип **getCellType** https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html#FORMULA

Общее описание здесь
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--